# rxjs module not found in VS2019 but is found with the tsc cli

Tags: angularjs, typescript, rxjs, visual-studio-2019

An old angularjs project I have added TypeScript to with the idea of moving to Angular 2+ eventually.

I want to use rxjs observables in my TypeScript code but trying to do so has some unusual behaviour. Visual studio 2019 cannot find the typings but visual studio code can.
 When compiled via tsc directly it builds fine and running it from visual studio 2019 is also working as expected, but when writing code [visual studio cannot find it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VyJcP.png) with a "cannot find module 'rxjs'" message and no type information is displayed.

I installed rxjs via `npm install rxjs --save` and can see some typing files in the mode_modules/rxjs folder.

My tsconfig is:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "sourceMap": true,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "module": "es6",
    "target": "es5",
    "allowJs": true,
    "lib": [ "dom", "es7" ],
    "moduleResolution": "node"
  },
  "include": [
    "app"
    ],
  "exclude": ["**/lib"]
}
```

package.json dependencies

```
 "dependencies": {
    "@types/angular": "^1.7.0",
    "natives": "^1.1.6",
    "rxjs": "^6.5.5",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.5.5"
  },
```

If I import it directly from the directory it works.

```
import { Observable } from './../../../node_modules/rxjs/internal/Observable';
```

I am not sure where to look next, I have spent quite a bit of time trying to search for a solution.

Comment: Yeah, the typings file should be included in rxjs. Does it work if you try something like import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable'?

Comment: No luck there @JamesIngold. Same module not found error.

Comment: have you tried re starting your machine and also try removing node_modules folder and do npm install and try ?

Answer (score 0):

I just had this problem.

It turns out, I mistakenly used npm to add a package when I have already established yarn as my package manager. This is what caused the problem.

I fixed by deleting the node_modules folder and running the following commands to reinstall the packages.

```
yarn cache clean --force
yarn install
```